# Show previously selected checkboxes in jsp, Java Spring

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp, say A, where there is a checkbox from which the user selects some boxes. I save these user selections.

Now I do some other staff, which includes changing view (jsp), and after some time I go back to jsp A.

I want to show the same checkbox table from before, but with the previously selected boxese already checked (remeber I have these saved and available bc I passed the list of selection to the model as an attribute). How can I do that?

I've tried stuff like the following but didn't work

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${flavourList}" var="flavour">
        <tr>
            <td><form:checkbox path="flavours" value="${flavour}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${flavour.name}" 
                       checked=<c:if test="${flavoursChecked.contains(${flavour})">"checked"</c:if>/>
                 </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to save the changes in flavoursChecked.  Pass it to the page that display flavourList.

Comment: @ChengThao    I did that but then the only checkboxes shown are the ones the user previously selected, not all the checkboxes (both the previously selected and the non-selected ones)